# python Tkinter Turtle screen background

Tags: python, tkinter, screen, turtle-graphics

When I try to set my turtle screen background I get this error:

[image]

this is the code part:

```
   sc=turtle.Screen()  
   turtle.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 1000,1000)  
   sc.bgpic('images.jpg')
```

and yes the image is saved under the same file name I called it in the code.

Comment: Looks like your `'images.jpg'` file might be corrupt. Try opening it in a different program.

Answer (score 0):

Per the turtle documentation, `bgpic()` only accepts GIF files, not JPEG:

> turtle.bgpic(picname=None)
>
> Parameters: picname – a string, **name of a gif-file** or "nopic", or None
>
> Set background image or return name of current backgroundimage. If
>   picname is a filename, set the corresponding image as background. If
>   picname is "nopic", delete background image, if present. If picname is
>   None, return the filename of the current backgroundimage.